# What is the term for redundant computational tasks leading to large computational cost?

Tags: resources, terminology

I want to use the term "memory leak" because that's the closest thing I can think of that's similar to this.

A product I use makes several calls to Google assets which are not only computationally expensive for the company but may also cost money if Google charges for a certain number of uses of their API.

There is only a need for them to make one call, but they're making several calls. If it's affecting more than just my account, it would be an extreme computational expense on their end.

I would like to know the term for this computationally expensive non-memory leak. Excessive resource use?